# How to get Bitcoin value for corresponding USD value in ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, bitcoin, blockchain

I want to get Bitcoin value for corresponding USD value and store it in table or variable. I got this URL from which I can get a Bitcoin value for USK amount. I searched on blockchain and I found this URL.

For example:

```
500usd = 0.76105818 btc
```

I tried:

```
https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=500
```

at the end, its USD value which we want to convert in Bitcoin.
I want to get the result in the variable in C# (backend).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to just make call to server and parse the response.

```
var uri = String.Format("https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value={0}", 500);

WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
var data = client.DownloadString(uri);

var result = Convert.ToDouble(data);
```

Comment: so intresult will return the coresponding bitcoin value for usd value? but it does not return correct bitcoin value..

Comment: Thank you so much.. its was time saver. thank you. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Install-Package CoinMarketCapClient

using CoinMarketCap;

```
public static async Task<double> GetBitcoinInUsd(double usd){
            //https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/
            CoinMarketCapClient client = CoinMarketCapClient.GetInstance();
            var entity = await client.GetTickerAsync("bitcoin");
            return entity.PriceUsd * usd;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

var uri = String.Format(@"https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value={0}",1);

WebClient client = new WebClient();

client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

var data = client.DownloadString(uri);

var result = 1/Convert.ToDouble(data.Replace('.',',')); //you will receive 1 btc = result;

Answer (score -1):

There are several APIs out there that will allow you to request the prices for a list of crypto currencies, and/or fiat currencies. The problem is that all the APIs do it in a disparate way. The follow on from that is that any one could be down at any given time, so you need to have some failure tolerance built in. I.e. the code should attempt to use one API, and if that fails, move to the next. Of course, this is further complicated by the fact that price is subjective and localised to a given country, exchange and so on. So, getting an accurate value is very difficult.

Here is example Crypto Compare client from CryptoCurrency.Net (https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/CryptoCurrency.Net/blob/master/src/CryptoCurrency.Net/APIClients/PriceEstimationClients/CryptoCompareClient.cs):

```
public class CryptoCompareClient : PriceEstimationClientBase, IPriceEstimationClient
    {
        public CryptoCompareClient(IRestClientFactory restClientFactory) : base(restClientFactory)
        {
            RESTClient = restClientFactory.CreateRESTClient(new Uri("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com"));
        }

        protected override Func<GetPricesArgs, Task<EstimatedPricesModel>> GetPricesFunc { get; } = async a =>
        {
            var retVal = new EstimatedPricesModel();

            if (a.Currencies.ToList().Count == 0)
            {
                return retVal;
            }

            retVal.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;

            var symbolsPart = string.Join(",", a.Currencies.Select(c => c.Name));

            var priceJson = await a.RESTClient.GetAsync<string>($"data/pricemultifull?fsyms={symbolsPart}&tsyms={a.FiatCurrency}");

            var jObject = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(priceJson);

            var rawNode = (JObject)jObject.First.First;

            foreach (JProperty coinNode in rawNode.Children())
            {
                var fiatNode = (JProperty)coinNode.First().First;

                var allProperties = fiatNode.First.Children().Cast<JProperty>().ToList();

                var change24HourProperty = allProperties.FirstOrDefault(p => string.Compare(p.Name, "CHANGEPCT24HOUR", true) == 0);
                var priceProperty = allProperties.FirstOrDefault(p => string.Compare(p.Name, "PRICE", true) == 0);

                var price = (decimal)priceProperty.Value;
                var change24Hour = (decimal)change24HourProperty.Value;
                retVal.Result.Add(new CoinEstimate { CurrencySymbol = new CurrencySymbol(coinNode.Name), ChangePercentage24Hour = change24Hour, FiatEstimate = price, LastUpdate = DateTime.Now });
            }

            //Extreme hack. It's better to show zero than nothing at all and get the coins stuck
            foreach (var currency in a.Currencies)
            {
                if (retVal.Result.FirstOrDefault(ce => ce.CurrencySymbol.Equals(currency)) == null)
                {
                    retVal.Result.Add(new CoinEstimate { ChangePercentage24Hour = 0, CurrencySymbol = currency, FiatEstimate = 0, LastUpdate = DateTime.Now });
                }
            }

            return retVal;
        };
}
```

The PriceEstimationManager will flick through APIs until it finds one that works (https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/CryptoCurrency.Net/blob/master/src/CryptoCurrency.Net/APIClients/PriceEstimationClients/PriceEstimationManager.cs):

```
public class PriceEstimationManager
{
    #region Fields
    private readonly Collection<IPriceEstimationClient> _Clients = new Collection<IPriceEstimationClient>();
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public PriceEstimationManager(IRestClientFactory restClientFactory)
    {
        foreach (var typeInfo in typeof(PriceEstimationManager).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.DefinedTypes)
        {
            var type = typeInfo.AsType();

            if (typeInfo.ImplementedInterfaces.Contains(typeof(IPriceEstimationClient)))
            {
                _Clients.Add((IPriceEstimationClient)Activator.CreateInstance(type, restClientFactory));
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// TODO: This needs to be averaged. The two current clients give wildly different values. Need to include some Australian exchanges etc.
    /// </summary>
    public async Task<EstimatedPricesModel> GetPrices(IEnumerable<CurrencySymbol> currencySymbols, string fiatCurrency)
    {
        //Lets try a client that hasn't been used before if there is one
        var client = _Clients.FirstOrDefault(c => c.AverageCallTimespan.TotalMilliseconds == 0);
        var currencies = currencySymbols.ToList();
        if (client != null)
        {
            try
            {
                return await client.GetPrices(currencies, fiatCurrency);
            }
            catch
            {
                //Do nothing
            }
        }

        foreach (var client2 in _Clients.OrderBy(c => c.SuccessRate).ThenBy(c => c.AverageCallTimespan).ToList())
        {
            try
            {
                return await client2.GetPrices(currencies, fiatCurrency);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Log("Error Getting Prices", ex, nameof(PriceEstimationManager));
            }
        }

        throw new Exception("Can't get prices");
    }
    #endregion
}
```

At a higher level, you can use the code like this (https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/CryptoCurrency.Net/blob/master/src/CryptoCurrency.Net.UnitTests/PricingTests.cs):

```
public async Task GetUSDBitcoinPrice()
{
    var priceEstimationManager = new PriceEstimationManager(new RESTClientFactory());
    var estimatedPrice = await priceEstimationManager.GetPrices(new List<CurrencySymbol> { CurrencySymbol.Bitcoin }, "USD");
    Console.WriteLine($"Estimate: {estimatedPrice.Result.First().FiatEstimate}");
}
```

As more pricing clients are added, it will get more and more reliable.